# C# NuGet package error in Azure DevOps with image

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, nuget-package

I'm creating a NuGet package to distribute in my organization. Following a [post](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/net-core/nuget-package-with-azure-devops/) online, the pipeline is working. In Azure DevOps I created the **Artifacts**, the pipeline buils the NuGet package and push it in the Artifacts as I expected. I'm using Visual Studio 2021.

So, in the property of the project I selected an icon.

[image]

I committed this change and now Azure DevOps gives me an error. So, I created a folder in the project called `Images` and here I pasted the image I want to use and updated the path from Visua Studio. The error is the same.

> ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS7064: Error opening icon file /home/vsts/work/1/s/Images/psc_logo.ico -- Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Images/psc_logo.ico'.

Also, in Visual Studio I see the package but the description and the author are different from what I filled in the property.

[image]

How can I fix it?

### Update

Although I added the properties in the `.csproj` file, Azure DevOps ignores completely them.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Description>Collection of useful functions</Description>
    <Copyright>Enrico Rossini</Copyright>
    <PackageTags>extensions, c#, net50</PackageTags>
    <SignAssembly>False</SignAssembly>
    <Company>Enrico Rossini</Company>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Collection of useful functions</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <PackageIcon>psc_logo.png</PackageIcon>
    <ApplicationIcon>psc_logo.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <Authors>Enrico Rossini</Authors>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.2</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="psc_logo.ico" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
    <None Include="psc_logo.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You see in the picture below that `authors` and `description` has the default values.

[image]

### Update

The project is Azure DevOps is exactly the same as the local one. The project settings are the same as above.

When I run the pipeline in Azure DevOps I have this warning

> WARNING: NU5118: File '/home/vsts/work/1/s/PSC.Extensions/bin/Debug/net5.0/ref/PSC.Extensions.dll' is not added because the package already contains file 'lib/net50/PSC.Extensions.dll'
>
> WARNING: NU5115: Description was not specified. Using 'Description'.
>
> WARNING: NU5115: Author was not specified. Using 'vsts'.

So, I changed the pipeline and in the package step I added the

- task: NuGetCommand@2

  ```
  displayName: Prepare the package
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'PackageVersion'
    buildProperties: 'Authors="Enrico Rossini";Description="Test"'
  ```

but nothing.

Comment: Devops is expecting that file to be in the source path (`/s`), and it's not. It looks like you should either check it in, or fix your path to your nuget

Answer (score 2):

> C# NuGet package error in Azure DevOps with image

According to the error message, it seems you need add the file `psc_logo.ico` to the source control, the repo.

But, if you want to specify the icon for the package, then the way you are setting the icon is incorrect.

The package settings should be specified in the **Package** tab.

And for the icon of the package, you could specify following `Property` in the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <None Include="images\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="\"/>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

You could check the document [icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#icon) and [Packing an icon image file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-an-icon-image-file).

For the `description` and the `author`, make sure you have define them in the project file and the nuget pack task works on your project file `.csproj`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <Description>Test project</Description>
    <Authors>Leo</Authors>
    <PackageIcon>psc.png</PackageIcon>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: @EnricoRossini, I checked your settings, it works fine on the local, please check the package info which generated in the local, if it is different from the result produced by devops, then you need to check the build log of devops and the project file in the repo.